# Creating a datepicker in an activity when pressing a button

Tags: android, datepicker, android-spinner

I am trying to create a datepicker when I click on a button in an activity. But it appears in the runtime with a calendar. I would like to get the same result as (android:datePickerMode="spinner") in XML. I tried the below approach, but it does not work.

```
private DatePicker createNewDatePicker( ) {
    layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    newDatePicker= new DatePicker(this);
    newDatePicker.setSpinnersShown(true);
    newDatePicker.setCalendarViewShown(false);
    newDatePicker.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
    return newDatePicker;
}
```

Could anyone please suggest a solution?

Comment: on which min API You are working?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(this, AddIProfile.this,

calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR), calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH), 

calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));


findViewById(R.id.dateButton).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

 @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                datePickerDialog.show();

            }

        });

@Override

    public void onDateSet(DatePicker datePicker, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {

        calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);

        calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, month);

        calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);

        date = calendar.getTime();


    }
```